# Sum involving Bernoulli polynomial evaluated at $-1$ and binomial convolution. Weird convergence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $$H_x^m$$ be the $m$th generalized harmonic numbers, and $$B_r(x)$$ be the $r$th Bernoulli polynomial.

I need help figuring out this sum for my high school science fair research:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(2\pi x)^{2k} }{(2k+1)!}(\sum_{p=0}^\infty (H_x^p-1)B_p(-1){2k+1 \choose p}) $$

We assume integer $x$.
Each attempt I do keeps getting thwarted by some weird convergence.
Some attempts:

1. Swapping the order of summation. The sum looks like they converge over the two variables.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(2\pi x)^{2k} }{(2k+1)!}(\sum_{p=0}^\infty (H_x^p-1)B_p(-1){2k+1 \choose p}) $$
= $$\sum_{p=0}^\infty (H_x^p-1)B_p(-1) \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(2\pi x)^{2k}  {2k+1 \choose p}}{(2k+1)!}$$

Expanding out $2k+1$ choose $p$,

$$\sum_{p=0}^\infty (H_x^p-1)B_p(-1) \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(2\pi x)^{2k}  }{(p!)(2k+1-p)!}$$=
$$\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{(H_x^p-1)B_p(-1)}{p!} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(2\pi x)^{2k}  }{(2k+1-p)!}$$
Since we have integer $x$, the second sum will be not 0 for $p = 0$, 3,5,7,9,11..., and the cosines involved in the sum go to 1. Because of this, the sum becomes the $p = 0$ case $+$ the $p =$ odd numbers case:

$$\frac{(1-H_x^0)B_0(-1)}{0!} +\sum_{p=1}^\infty \frac{(H_x^{2p+1}-1)B_{2p+1}(-1)}{(2p+1)!} (2\pi x)^{2p}(-1)^p$$

It turns out to be wrong though. I played a bit more with this idea, but I couldn't figure anything out.

2. Binomial convolution.
   Noting that the $2k+1$ choose $p$ term is in binomial convolution with the harmonic numbers and Bernoulli polynomial term, we attempt to exploit that binomial convolutions can be made with multiplying two exponential generating functions.

Noting that:
$$ \frac{e^{-x}x}{e^x-1} = \sum_{p=0}^\infty  \frac{B_p(-1)x^p}{p!} $$
then
$$ \frac{e^{\frac{-2\pi x}{j}}2\pi x}{j(e^{\frac {2\pi x}{j}}-1)} = \sum_{p=0}^\infty  \frac{B_p(-1)(2\pi x)^p}{p! j^p} $$
then
$$ e^{2\pi x}\frac{e^{\frac{-2\pi x}{j}}2\pi x}{j(e^{\frac {2\pi x}{j}}-1)} = \sum_{p=0}^\infty  \frac{(2\pi x)^p}{p!}(\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{B_r(-1)}{j^r}{p \choose r}) $$

Let this function be f(x). Then the sum for the alternating odd terms is
(f(ix)-f(ix))/2i for imaginary $i$. Thus, the sum then turns to

$$ \frac {1}{2i} (e^{2\pi x}\frac{e^{\frac{-2\pi x}{j}}2\pi x}{j(e^{\frac {2\pi x}{j}}-1)} + e^{-2\pi x}\frac{e^{\frac{2\pi x}{j}}2\pi x}{j(e^{\frac {-2\pi x}{j}}-1)}) = \sum_{p=0}^\infty  \frac{(2\pi x)^{2p+1}}{(2p+1)!}(\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{B_r(-1)}{j^r}{2p+1 \choose r}) $$

Dividing by $2\pi x$ to get closer to our original sum + noting that $e^{2\pi x}$ goes to 1 for integer $x$ + an $i$ in both the numerator and denominator, we get

$$ \frac {1}{2j} (\frac{e^{\frac{-2\pi x}{j}}}{(e^{\frac {2\pi x}{j}}-1)} + \frac{e^{\frac{2\pi x}{j}}}{(e^{\frac {-2\pi x}{j}}-1)}) = \sum_{p=0}^\infty  \frac{(2\pi x)^{2p}}{(2p+1)!}(\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{B_r(-1)}{j^r}{2p+1 \choose r}) $$

This ends up equaling.

$$ \frac {1}{2j} (-2cos(\frac {2\pi x}{j}) -1) = \sum_{p=0}^\infty  \frac{(2\pi x)^{2p}}{(2p+1)!}(\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{B_r(-1)}{j^r}{2p+1 \choose r}) $$

Taking out the first term in the RHS we get that

$$ \frac {1}{2j} (-2cos(\frac {2\pi x}{j}) -1) -1 + \frac {3}{2j} = \sum_{p=1}^\infty  \frac{(2\pi x)^{2p}}{(2p+1)!}(\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{B_r(-1)}{j^r}{2p+1 \choose r}) $$

Now we sum from $j=2$ to $j=x$. The resulting sum turns out again to be wrong. It actually ends up equaling the swapped summation one in (1).

Why is this sum not working out. Convergence seems to happen in calculations for the original sum for $x$ bigger than $2\pi$, so it probably converges. And are there any nicer ways we can express the initial sum? I will cite what I use.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer will surprise you. But first swapping the order of summation needs some justifications. Another precision: $\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ p\end{array}\right) = 0$ if $n<p$, the values $p=0$ is not well defined.   To justify the swap is the only remaining problem.

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{rl}
            A = & \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2 \pi x)^{2 k}}{(2 k+1) !}\left(\sum_{p=1}^{\infty}\left(H_x^p-1\right) B_p(-1)\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 k+1 \\
p
\end{array}\right)\right) \\
             = & \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2 \pi x)^{2 k}}{(2 k+1) !}\left(\sum_{p=1}^{2k+1}\left(H_x^p-1\right) B_p(-1)\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 k+1 \\
p
\end{array}\right)\right)
        \end{array}
    \end{equation*}
To do the swap is not direct. remark that$1\leq p\leq 2k+1$ that means that $p-1 \leq 2k$. I will divide it into 2 case either p is even or odd

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{rl}
            A = & \sum\limits_{p=1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=p}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2 \pi x)^{2 k}}{(2 k+1) !}\left(H_x^{2p}-1\right) B_{2p}(-1)\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 k+1 \\
2p
\end{array}\right) +  \sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=p+1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(2 \pi x)^{2 k}}{(2 k+1) !}\left(H_x^{2p+1}-1\right) B_{2p+1}(-1)\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 k+1 \\
2p +1
\end{array}\right) \\
             = & \sum\limits_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p}-1\right) B_{2p}(-1)}{(2p)!}\sum\limits_{k=p}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2 \pi x)^{2 k}}{(2 k+1 - 2p) ! 
             } +  \sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p+1}-1\right) B_{2p+1}(-1)}{(2 p+1) !}\sum\limits_{k=p+1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(2 \pi x)^{2 k}}{(2 k+1 - 2p-1) !} \\
             = & \sum\limits_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p}-1\right) B_{2p}(-1)}{(2p)!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+p}(2 \pi x)^{2 (k+p)}}{(2 k+1) ! 
             } +  \sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p+1}-1\right) B_{2p+1}(-1)}{(2 p+1) !}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+p}(2 \pi x)^{2 (k+p)}}{(2 k) !}
              \\
             = & \sum\limits_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p}-1\right) B_{2p}(-1) (-1)^{p}(2 \pi x)^{2 p-1}}{(2p)!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}(2 \pi x)^{2 k+1}}{(2 k+1) ! 
             } +  \sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p+1}-1\right) B_{2p+1}(-1)(-1)^{p}(2 \pi x)^{2 p}}{(2 p+1) !}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}(2 \pi x)^{2 (k)}}{(2 k) !}
        \end{array}
    \end{equation*}
let's recall that
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{rcl}
e^x & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}\\
\cos(x) & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
\sin(x) & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
\text{ch}(x) & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
\text{sh}(x) & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
   \end{array}
\end{equation*}
back to our problem
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{rl}
        A =  &   \sum\limits_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p}-1\right) B_{2p}(-1) (-1)^{p}(2 \pi x)^{2 p-1}}{(2p)!}\sin(2\pi x) +  \sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p+1}-1\right) B_{2p+1}(-1)(-1)^{p}(2 \pi x)^{2 p}}{(2 p+1) !}(cos(2 \pi x)-1)\\
         = & 0
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}

Comment: When I test the sum for x =7 and let infinity = 50(adding up 50 terms) the sum goes to -2.80486…. Then when I let infinity equal 130 it goes to -2.80486… too. The sum looks like it converges to something not always 0.

Comment: II don't know maybe the way i did the computation is flawed. can you look up the swapping part? This may suppose that the absolute convergence of the series may not be true. that's is the justification that the order of summation cannot be changed. let me put a new post with the convergence condition.

Answer (score 0):

Testing if swapping is correct. I think the answer will surprise you. Another precision: $\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ p\end{array}\right) = 0$ if $n<p$, the values $p=0$ are not well-defined.   To justify the swap is the only remaining problem.

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{rl}
            A = & \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{p=1}^{2k+1}|\frac{(-1)^k(2 \pi |x|)^{2 k}}{(2 k+1) !}\left(H_x^p-1\right) B_p(-1)\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 k+1 \\
p
\end{array}\right)|
        \end{array}
    \end{equation*}
Here swapping is allowed then, we can:
To do the swap is not direct. remark that$1\leq p\leq 2k+1$ that means that $p-1 \leq 2k$. I will divide it into 2 case either p is even or odd

\begin{equation*}
        \begin{array}{rl}
            A = & \sum\limits_{p=1}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=p}^{\infty} \frac{(2 \pi |x|)^{2 k}}{(2 k+1) !}\left(H_x^{2p}-1\right) |B_{2p}(-1)|\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 k+1 \\
2p
\end{array}\right) +  \sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=p+1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2 \pi |x|)^{2 k}}{(2 k+1) !}\left(H_x^{2p+1}-1\right) |B_{2p+1}(-1)|\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 k+1 \\
2p +1
\end{array}\right) \\
             = & \sum\limits_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p}-1\right) |B_{2p}(-1)|}{(2p)!}\sum\limits_{k=p}^{\infty} \frac{(2 \pi |x|)^{2 k}}{(2 k+1 - 2p) ! 
             } +  \sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p+1}-1\right) |B_{2p+1}(-1)|}{(2 p+1) !}\sum\limits_{k=p+1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k(2 \pi |x|)^{2 k}}{(2 k+1 - 2p-1) !} \\
             = & \sum\limits_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p}-1\right) |B_{2p}(-1)|}{(2p)!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2 \pi |x|)^{2 (k+p)}}{(2 k+1) ! 
             } +  \sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p+1}-1\right) |B_{2p+1}(-1)|}{(2 p+1) !}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2 \pi |x|)^{2 (k+p)}}{(2 k) !}
              \\
             = & \sum\limits_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p}-1\right) |B_{2p}(-1)|(2 \pi |x|)^{2 p-1}}{(2p)!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2 \pi |x|)^{2 k+1}}{(2 k+1) ! 
             } +  \sum\limits_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p+1}-1\right) |B_{2p+1}(-1)|(2 \pi |x|)^{2 p}}{(2 p+1) !}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2 \pi |x|)^{2 (k)}}{(2 k) !}
        \end{array}
    \end{equation*}
let's recall that
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{rcl}
e^x & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n!}\\
\cos(x) & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
\sin(x) & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
\text{ch}(x) & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\\
\text{sh}(x) & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\
   \end{array}
\end{equation*}
back to our problem
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{rl}
        A =  &   \sum\limits_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p}-1\right) |B_{2p}(-1)| (2 \pi |x|)^{2 p-1} \sinh(2\pi x)}{(2p)!} + \sum\limits_{p=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_x^{2p+1}-1\right) |B_{2p+1}(-1)| (2 \pi |x|)^{2 p} \cosh(2\pi x)}{(2p+1)!}
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}
I don't know how to go further. Can you complete the proof?
Edit: I saw that the convergence radius of the Bernouli polynomials generating function is $2\pi$ So for $|x|\geq1$ we don't have convergence for any of the series above. We can't use the swapping method.I will edit the earlier post to takes this into account.

Comment: I'm also not sure how to continue further. I will probably change my approach then.